# How to select the first three elements of a IEnumerable object?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

That's it. The question is in the title

I was looking for a cleaner way than the using for...break;

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it!

```
var items = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var results = items.Take(3);
```